# Syntax error when attempting to run basic C program

Tags: c, ubuntu

I am new to using Ubuntu and commonly run into errors such as the one below and cannot find a fix for it.

```
int main(){

    int myFile;
    char buffer[360];

    myFile = open("readMe.txt", O_RDONLY, 0756);
    if(myFile < 0){
            printf("Error.\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    int readInfo;
    readInfo = read(myFile, buffer, 360);

    if (close(myFile) < 0){
            printf("Error.\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    else {

            printf("%i\n", readInfo);
            printf("%.*s\n", readInfo, buffer);
    }
    return(0);
```

I have given the file the ability to execute with chmod +x, but when run I receive:

```
./assignment3: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./assignment3: line 1: `int main(){'
```

I seem to have this problem with other files as well, making me believe I am doing something wrong in making the file executable and running it, but I do not know what.

Comment: which language are you using? this looks like C which isn't a scripting language

Comment: Yes, I am writing in C. I am only trying to execute the file in the Ubuntu terminal to practice using the program and learn the language, as I have primarily used Python and Java before.

Comment: Unless you have a C interpreter (pro tip: you don't) the way to run a C program is to compile it.

Answer (score 3):

As someone mentioned, you need to *compile* it, which turns it into machine code (executable code). Rename it to `assignment3.c` and try

```
gcc -o assignment3 assignment3.c
```

Execute it with `./assignment3`.